# Open quickfix window without focusing it

Tags: vimrc, quickfix, makeprg, plugin-asyncrun

I run my `make` commands asynchronously in vim with the [asyncrun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim) plugin.

I use this code in my `.vimrc` to open the quickfix window automatically everytime I run an asynchronous make command in order to see the output.

```
augroup vimrc
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost * botright copen 8
augroup END
nnoremap <leader>m :AsyncRun -cwd=<root> make<CR>
```

I usually don't want to jump into the quickfix window, but only open it and see the output. I couldn't find a way how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same thinking for a solution as the other answer here has (`wincmd p`). But I found it was not 100% reliable depending on what quickfix command type is being used.

If you have issues with that solution you might have some better luck with a solution that uses explicit window/buffer references. An easy approach is to save the current buffer name in a global variable and jump to its "buffer window number" after the QF command runs...

```
autocmd QuickFixCmdPre * let g:mybufname=bufname('%')
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost * botright copen 8 | exec bufwinnr(g:mybufname) . 'wincmd w'
```

Comment: @Jonas  Cool. You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Actually [asyncrun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim) has that feature. According to the [document](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim#quickfix-window):

> AsyncRun displays its output in quickfix window, so if you don't use `:copen {height}` to open quickfix window, you won't see any output. For convenience there is an option `g:asyncrun_open` for you.

So you just put this code `:let g:asyncrun_open = 8` in your `.vimrc`.

When you press `<leader>m`, [asyncrun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim) will open quickfix window automatically. 
I've tested that it will only open the quickfix window but still focus you r current window. Enjoy~

Answer (score 2):

Running `wincmd p` after the copen should work; you jump to the quickfix window and then right back to the window you were in e.g.

```
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost * botright copen 8 | wincmd p
```

see `:h wincmd`, `:h CTRL-W_p`